# Disqualifying consecutive characters in an Alphabetical Order. Sol [ASCII Format]

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, data-manipulation

I was given this problem by my friend. The question asks to remove all the alphabetically consecutive characters from the string input given.
So I did it using Javascript, I need expert help if I performed it precisely.

I thought using Array.prototype.reduce will be the best way, do we have other possible ways?

```
/**
 * @author Abhishek Mittal <abhishekmittaloffice@gmail.com>
 * @description function can deal with both any types followed in a consecutive manner in ASCII Chart.
 * @param {string} str 
 */
function improvise(str) {
    // Backup for original input.
    const bck = str || '';
    const bckArr = bck.split('').map( e => e.charCodeAt(0)); // converting the alphabets into its ASCII for simplicity and reducing the mayhem.

    let result = bckArr.reduce( (acc, n) => {
            // Setting up flag
            let flag1 = n - acc.rand[acc.rand.length - 1];
            let flag2 = n - acc.temp;

            if(flag1 === 1 || flag2 === 1) {
                (flag2 !== NaN && flag2 !== 1) ? acc.rand.pop() : null; // update the latest value with according to the case.
                acc.temp = n
            }else{
                acc.rand.push(n); // updating the random to latest state.
                acc.temp = null;
            }

        return acc;

    }, {rand: [], temp: null} /* setting up accumulative situation of the desired result */) 

    result = result.rand.map(e => String.fromCharCode(e)).join('')
    return result ? result : '' ;
}

function init() {
    const str = "ab145c";
    const final = improvise(str);
    console.log(final)
}
init();
```

Well, the output is coming out to be correct.
Input: ab145c
Output: 1c

Comment: Do we have a way to solve it using REGEX ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to solve this using any remotely reasonable regular expression, unfortunately.

I think it would be a lot clearer to use `.filter`, and check whether either the next character or the previous character is consecutive:

```js
const code = char => char
? char.charCodeAt(0)
: -2; // will not be === to any other codes after addition or subtraction
  
function improvise(str) {
  return [...str]
    .filter((char, i) => {
      const thisCode = code(char);
      return (
        thisCode !== code(str[i - 1]) + 1
        && thisCode !== code(str[i + 1]) - 1
      );
    })
    .join('');
}

console.log(improvise('ab145c'));
```

(alternatively, you could check *only* whether the next character is consecutive, but then you'd have to check the validity of the last character in the string as well)

If you need *continuously replace* characters until no consecutive characters remain, then keep calling `improvise`:

```js
const code = char => char
? char.charCodeAt(0)
: -2; // will not be === to any other codes after addition or subtraction
  
function improvise(str) {
  return [...str]
    .filter((char, i) => {
      const thisCode = code(char);
      return (
        thisCode !== code(str[i - 1]) + 1
        && thisCode !== code(str[i + 1]) - 1
      );
    })
    .join('');
}

let result = 'hishakmitalaaaaabbbbbbcccccclmnojqyz';
let same = false;
while (!same) {
  const newResult = improvise(result);
  if (newResult !== result) {
    result = newResult;
    console.log(result);
  } else {
    same = true;
  }
}
console.log('FINAL:', result);
```

Comment: Well, that's great code but it doesn't gives the exact solution to the problem, see:

Comment: Your question didn't specify that you needed to continuously replace characters until no consecutive ones remained, but if you do, it's a simple tweak, see edit - just keep replacing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's great code but it doesn't gives the exact solution to the problem, see:

```
INPUT: hishakmitalaaaaabbbbbbcccccclmnojqyz
```

i got

```
Output: shakmitalaaaabbbbcccccjq
```

you see 'ab' & 'bc' remains intact, we need to increase the number of loops maybe to check those, can increase complexity as well.
But, my solution doesn't as well gives me the answer I desire e.g. for the above string I should get

> ishakmitalaacccjq

but rather my solution gives

> shakmitalcccccjq

hope you understand the question. We need a change in the way we traverse throughout the string.

Comment: yes, it does. I tried it though, in my case I rather tried to reduce the complexity, but anyways, I guess we can go with your solution now.